# Remove directories that doesn't have a subdirectory with a certain name

Tags: bash, find

I would like to remove all the directories that do not have `directoryB`. The tree structure is like:

```
--directory1
         |
          directoryA---directoryB
         |
          directoryC
         |
          directoryD---directoryB
```

I have tried the below script within `directory1`:

```
du -a -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr
```

So I know that all the directories I want to remove have a size 8k. If I tried the script below outside `directory1` shows nearly everything within.

```
find directory1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -size 8
```

I think that my safe option is to remove the directories without `directoryB`. How can I do that?

Comment: Are they always at the same level? Or can they be at varying depths? I see you are using `-maxdepth 1` with find, but that was while you were checking sizes. If they are consistently at that same level, @oguz solution is perfect. If not, add `shopt -s globstar` and use `directory1/**/` to do the same thing at variable depth. You might want to turn globstar off afterwards - `set +o globstar`.

Comment: @PaulHodges, yes they are always at the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need *find* for this. A simple loop would work just fine.

```
for d in directory1/*/; do
  if ! test -d "${d}directoryB"; then
    echo rm -r "${d}"
  fi
done
```

Remove *echo* if you're happy with the output.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [`test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

1. `find .` Find in current working dir
2. `-type d` only folders
3. `-depth` depth-first mode <sup>[[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258057/does-the-depth-option-of-find-imply-depth-first-tree-traversal)</sup>
4. `-depth 1` force depth to 1
5. `! -exec test -e "{}/dirB/" \;` If this file does **not** contain `dirB`
6. `-print` print path

```sh
find . -type d -depth -depth 1 ! -exec test -e "{}/dirB/" \; -print
```

---

If the output seems fine, replace `-print` with `-exec rm -r "{}" \;` [to remove the folders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/finds-exec-rm-vs-delete):

```sh
find . -type d -depth -depth 1 ! -exec test -e "{}/dirB/" \; -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

---

Example:

```sh
$ tree
.
|-- dirA
|   `-- dirB
|-- dirC
|   `-- dirX
`-- dirD
    `-- dirB

6 directories, 0 files
$
$
$ find . -type d -depth -depth 1 ! -exec test -e "{}/dirB/" \; -exec rm -rf {} \;
$
$ tree
.
|-- dirA
|   `-- dirB
`-- dirD
    `-- dirB

4 directories, 0 files
$
```

Comment: This says *find: paths must precede expression: `1'* with GNU find.

Comment: Was still debugging the depth issue, should be fixed now.

Comment: Still the same error. What version of find do you have? Mine is `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0`.

Comment: Mm, not sure what version, `find --version` returns `illegal option`. Seems like a quite old version, any tips to get the actual version? `man find` doesn't show any version info, only the release:  September 28, 2011 BSD.

Comment: BSD find then. This answer would work fine on MacOS and BSD distros I guess, but not Linux

Comment: Try `$PWD` instead of `.`?